# How to handle default alert when using OpenUrl with tel://2373829239

Tags: ios, objective-c

After running this i am getting alert with two button as call and cancel.
Call button will navigate to dialer pad and place the call which is fine. But i want to perform some action on the click of Cancel button.

Here is my code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLupA.png)

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:123"];
NSString *escaped = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escaped]];
```

Comment: That you can't avoid.

Comment: I want to perform some operation on cancel button event.

Comment: Have you looked at using `"telprompt://1234567890"` instead of `"tel://`? The completion block returns false on cancel...

Comment: Thanks.Completion handler works for me.  "telprompt://" and  "tel://" wont make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments i got the answer.
   //For iPhone use this:

```
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",phoneNumber]]])
        {

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",phoneNumber]] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
            {
                {
                    if (success)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"inside call clikced");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"inside cancel clicked");
                    }
                }
            }];
        }


   // For iPad use this:


 CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *info = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    CTCarrier *carrier1 = [info subscriberCellularProvider];

    if (carrier1.mobileCountryCode.length == 0 || carrier1.mobileCountryCode.length == nil)
{
// false for iPad Air 2(which doesn't have cellular Provider)
}
```